# Animatable Hair?

Tags: particles, hair

So this is my first time posting on here, I have some experience with Blender, im pretty good with sculpting and 3D-Modeling but have to get some more knowledge on texturing as well as animating.
However, as a project in school I`m trying to produce an animated short of a few minutes at max. Now i have the model for my main character, did the retopoplogy and so on but i dont know how to create hair with realistic physics for my character that will do its job in animation.

I can only seem to find tutorials on how to do hair that doesnt move, so how do I apply physics to the hair?

If you don`t know but know a good tutorial about this subject a link to that will be enough to help me out big time.

Thanks in advance